# Can't figure out what is causing the side scroll on my website

Tags: php, html, css

I am building a website for some local business and I can't figure out what is causing the side scrolling. I must have been really tired and messed up somewhere. Any and all help would be wonderful. The link to the site is http://theparkwayrv.com

If you look, you'll see that there is a side scrolling bar. Please let me know if you can figure it out. I've gone over it like 10+ times and i'm losing my mind right now.

Thanks!

Comment: horizontal or vertical?

Comment: you dont want the right side scroll?

Comment: I don't want the horizontal scroll.

Comment: 6 answers and no marked answer till now. amazing, what is going on?

Comment: I think there's a minimum rep required to choose an answer. Only one of the many savvy people around up-voted the question. (Won't tell who :). Welcome to SO, Ajsmut. Lovely website. Consider scrolling 4 items at a time on that slider, though, if you have a say on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
body {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

to your CSS.

Generally, this is due to having items with `width` or `min-width` set to `100%` or `100vw` in your page. When the browser adds a vertical scrollbar to it (17px in Chrome), it makes it `100% + 17px`, hence the need to add a horizontal scroll. This, however, doesn't happen on most mobile UI's and any browser that uses `semi-transparent-show-on-scroll-only` scrollbars.

As very well spotted by [Tersosauros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35193790/1891677), the only one who, instead of providing a quickfix, like the rest of us, actually took the time to look for the real cause of your `body`s extra width, in your particular case, this is due to using Bootstrap classes incorrectly. You used `.row` independently, without being a direct child of `.container` and the page is wider with `30px`.

However, the *quickfix* still solves it. At least in this life, we're mostly payed for solutions, not for being right. Right? :)

Answer (score 3):

This issue is being caused by the `15px` left and right **margins** on `.row` (line #7, bootstrap.min.css) affecting the child `div` within the `parkway_about_page` `div`.  This is part of how [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) expects your page to be structured, as pointed out by [@Andrei Gheorghiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1891677/andrei-gheorghiu) .  If `parkway_about_page` were also a `.container` bootstrap would fix this for you.

Either option fixed it for me:

1. Add (as the many other 1-line answers with no explanations have suggested) `overflow-x: hidden;` to `#parkway_about_page`.

*---* **OR** *---*

2. Remove the margin(s) from the `.row` `div` underneath `parkway_about_page`, (or just remove the class entirely).

Comment: If you're keen on being *correct*, perhaps you should preach about how to use Bootstrap properly, not how to *fix* it. What you probably meant is **`.row` should always be a direct child of `.container`**.

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu True, the underlaying issue would be attributable to the incorrect use of Bootstrap.  However, looking at the CSS I think fixing all of those would be quire an undertaking!  I'll update my answer to mention `.container` though, good spot!

Comment: I also edited my answer, for completeness. Thanks for complying to SO's mission to **make the Internet better**.

Answer (score 1):

Use this css to your body section:

```
body{overflow-x: hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
  body {
        overflow-x:hidden;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

in body just put `overflow-x: hidden`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11140089)

Comment: Please add in the inline css of body e.g style="overflow-x:hidden"

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css file :

```
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```